# GAE db.ReferenceProperty Self referencing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to reference self via the db.ReferenceProperty, and is it possible to construct a list?

For example I have a class for User and I want a property for his/her friends that references the User class?

I'm currently using Python.

Edit:

So if I have this class:

```
class Node(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    neighbour = db.SelfReferenceProperty(collection_name="neighbours")

node1 = Node(name="node1")
node2 = Node(name="node2")
node1.neighbour = node2
node2.neighbour = node1
node1.put()
node2.put()
```

can I access a list of other nodes via `node1.neighbours` and `node2.neighbours`?

Or should I do this:

```
class Node(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    neighbour = db.ListProperty(Node)

node1 = Node(name="node1")
node2 = Node(name="node2")
node1.node = [node2]
node2.neighbour = [node1]
node1.put()
node2.put()
```

Also how would I be able to add/delete/modify the list of neighbours in **both** examples above?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#SelfReferenceProperty).

> **`class SelfReferenceProperty`**(verbose_name=`None`, collection_name=`None`, ...)
>
> A reference to another model instance of the same class. See [ReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html).
>
> Value type: [db.Key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html) ([see above](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#db_Key))

Comment: Added additional details, please refer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

See also this related SO question: [SelfReferenceProperty vs. ListProperty Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495709/selfreferenceproperty-vs-listproperty-google-app-engine)

Comment: Added additional details, please refer to the question.

Comment: My read of the docs indicate that you can't have a list of `SelfReferenceProperties` like you can of strings or ints.